# Setting Apache SSL path dynamically based on domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, path, dynamic

Trying to replace SSL path with the current domain.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                <VirtualHost *:443>
                        ServerAlias *
                        UseCanonicalName Off
                        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                        SSLEngine on
                        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.crt
                        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.key
                </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But this throws error on save.

```
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

I come to know %0 only works for

```
VirtualDocumentRoot
VirtualDocumentRootIP
VirtualScriptAlias
VirtualScriptAliasIP
```

Any suggestions to achieve this in SSL path? TIA.